# from wikipedia title to freebase mid

Tags: wikipedia, freebase

Is there a way to map Wikipedia title link to Freebase mids?

For example, wikipedia titles are:

From_Russia_with_Love_(film),
John_Barry_(composer),
Lionel_Bart,
Matt_Monro

```
 [{ "mid": null, "id": "/en/matt_monro" }]
```

It works for titles like "Matt_Monro", "Lionel_Bart", but not "from_russia_with_love_(film)" or "john_barry_(composer)"

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The correct key to use is `/wikipedia/en_title/Matt_Monro`.  There's no guarantee that `/en/matt_monro` points the same place (and newer topics don't have keys in the `/en' namespace).

The Wikipedia titles which contain special characters, they need to be encoded using Freebase's key escaping scheme http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_key_escaping  For your first example, the key would be `/wikipedia/en_title/From_Russia_with_Love_$0028film$0029`