# How can I access Freebase data for Brazil?

Tags: freebase

I've had good luck using the `/wikipedia/en_title/<title>` key referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276278/from-wikipedia-title-to-freebase-mid). But for some topics, it yields very minimal data:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/wikipedia/en/Brazil?filter=commons'
{
 "id": "/m/0ng44ys",
 ...
}
```

Looking up this mid [on Freebase](http://freebase.com/m/0ng44ys) shows a shell of a topic. Specifically, it lacks descriptions, statistics and the myriad other facts you'd expect a large country to have in Freebase. The correct MID for Brazil is `/m/015fr`, which appears nowhere in the API response.

Before I start making a Wikipedia Title → MID monkey patch spreadsheet, is there a way to deal with this issue and reliably map Wikipedia titles to Freebase Topics?

Comment: Isn't it enough to limit the language to Portuguese ?

Comment: It looks like this was a transient issue -- the response to my `curl` command looks right now.